# Can Indian PSLV take ISRO to Mars?

Tags: mars, isro, pslv

Is the [Polar Satellite Launch Vehicle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSLV) capable of taking a 1,350 kg orbiter from the Earth to Mars as [this article](http://www.timesofindia.com/india/Isro-kicks-off-Mars-mission-campaign-with-PSLV-assembly/articleshow/21636884.cms) states?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, but to do so they're having to make significant compromises to the mission.  It was [originally](http://www.planetary.org/blogs/emily-lakdawalla/2013/07290600-MAVEN-MOM.html) intended to fly on India's next generation, significantly higher performing, Geosynchronous Satellite Launch Vehicle ([GSLV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geosynchronous_Satellite_Launch_Vehicle)) but delays and problems (3 of 7 flights have failed catastrophically, only 2 were fully successful) in that program forced them to use the older Polar Satellite Launch Vehicle ([PSLV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_Satellite_Launch_Vehicle)) instead.

The [MOM/Mangalyaan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mangalyaan) probe has a higher fuel to payload mix than the NASA/ESA probes mentioned above, and will be entering in a highly inclined orbit to save on the amount of fuel needed to enter orbit.  My supposition is that a large fraction of the fuel in the orbiter originally intended to put it in a low Mars orbit is instead being used to compensate for the less powerful launch and send it into interplanetary transfer orbit instead.

[image: MOM/Mangalyaan mission profile]

<sup>MOM / Mangalyaan mission profile compiled by and featured in [Mail Online India article](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/indiahome/indianews/article-2308766/Mars-Ahoy-Indian-scientists-gung-ho-putting-orbiter-Red-Planet.html)</sup>

The highly inclined 80,000 / 580 km orbit means it will only spend a minority of its time close to the planet, and severely limiting it's sensors effectiveness except for a small fraction of each orbit. However, in some ways this is less severe a problem than it may first seem. Some of the instruments are cameras: And for imaging purposes the limiting factor is not how fast pictures can be taken by the orbiter; but the low bandwidth available to return data to Earth. As a result for imaging, the limitation will primarily be in what they can take pictures of at any given time; not the total number they can send home.

Comparing it to other Mars orbiters:

- NASA's [Mars Reconnaissance Orbiter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Reconnaissance_Orbite) is 2180 kg fueled / 1031 kg empty. It was launched on an Atlas 401 which can deliver 9800 kg to a Low Earth Orbit (LEO). The standard PSLV can only deliver 3250 kg to LEO. The [TOI article](http://articles.timesofindia.indiatimes.com/2013-08-06/india/41130623_1_mars-orbiter-mission-lyman-alpha-photometer-mars-colour-camera) says the launch will be done with the PSLV-XL which can deliver 12.5% more mass to a Sun-Synchronous Orbit (SSO); assuming a similar increase to LEO it would scale to 3650 kg. That's only 37% of the rocket power; but for an orbiter that's 62% as massive.
- The 1030 kg [Mars Global Surveyor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Global_Surveyor) was launched on a Delta 7925 rocket. The Delta family can put between 2700 and 6100 kg in LEO; but Wikipedia doesn't have a per variant breakdown in performance. If launched on a lower power model, performance would be similar to what the PSLV offers; if it was a high performance model, the ~2:1 gap vs the MRO Atlas V-401 remains.
- ESA's [Mars Express](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Express) was 1123 kg fueled and launched on a [Soyuz-FG/Fregat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soyuz-FG) combo that could put 7800 kg into LEO. This is an even larger performance gap than with the MRO.